# How to sync files using symmetricDS Pro and archive it to another folder in source node

Tags: database, symmetricds

I am using [SymmetricDS](http://www.symmetricds.org/) Pro 3.5.18 with 800 store nodes and a 1 corp node only.

I have in the store nodes `Source folder` having "specific files" , I want to send it to corp node in "target folder" and after that I want to move synchronized files to "archive folder" in source node.

```
Source folder >> 'D:\OracleRetailStore\Server\pos\bin\POSLog'
Specific files >> 'RTLOG*.DAT'    
Target folder >> '/u01/rmsbatch/data/in/RTLOG/incoming'
Archive folder >> 'D:\OracleRetailStore\Server\pos\bin\POSLog\archive'
```

could you please help me to create this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

SymmetricDS does not support the archiving of transferred files. There is support being added in 3.6 (next major release) for deleting files on the source node after the transfer is complete. I've added an issue to support archiving files once a transfer is complete.

You can track the issue here...
http://www.symmetricds.org/issues/view.php?id=1682

This will most likely make it into 3.6. Let me know if you are interested in a snapshot build for testing before release.

Here is a file-sync walk through for reference.
http://www.jumpmind.com/blog/file-sync-made-easy

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. please let me know how can I move files from source folder to archive folder in the client after it is synchronized to target folder.

Comment: I'll update my response since I did not understand what you were originally asking.